# number of strings using Kleene star

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Which of the following strings is not in the language 
(a + bb)* (bab + aba) (bb + aa*)

Select one:

a. bbabbabaaaaaaaaa

b. bbabbbabbb

c. bbabbabbbbabbababb

d. bbabbababbaabb

I am having a hard time with this since they all seem to be in the language when broken down.

a --> bb/a/bb/aba/aa/aa/aa/aa

b -->bb/a/bb/bab/bb

c -->  bb/a/bb/a/bb/bb/a/bb/aba/bb

d --> bb/a/bb/aba/bb/aa/bb

Is there something about the kleene rules that I am missing or is the problem incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decomposition of (d) doesn’t match the regular expression

$$(a+bb)^*(bab+aba)(bb+aa^*)\;.$$

That regular expression allows only a single $bb$ after the $aba$ or $bab$ that you match with $bab+aba$, and you’ve used two.

Comment: oh i see. Because the * is on the aa and not on the expression, correct?

Comment: @Varoag: Almost. Note that the $*$ isn’t even on $aa$: that would be $(aa)^*$. It’s just on the second $a$, so that $aa^*$ gives you any string of one or more $a$s. Thus, after the $aba$ or $bab$ that you match up with the middle piece, you must have either $bb$ or $a^n$ for some $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Great. I did not notice that. Thank you!

Comment: @Varoag: You’re welcome!